# First Time using tkinter, unknown error: TclError

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a drop down menu for a alarm clock application to play some old rpg game sounds when the alarm activates. I keep getting this error and I'm not sure how to fix it:

self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))

TclError: unknown option "-class"

I've included everything I wrote because I'm not sure where the error is drawing from but I believe its after '### pick alarm sound menu'
    '''
    Standard Alarm Clock
    '''

```
import sys
import tkinter as tk 
import time
#import pygame

#pygame.init()

### load sounds
'''
opening_music = pygame.mixer.Sound("01 - Opening.ogg")
prelude_music = pygame.mixer.Sound("02 - Prelude.ogg")
nations_rage_music = pygame.mixer.Sound("03 - Nations Rage.ogg")
sanctuary_music = pygame.mixer.Sound("04 - Sanctuary.ogg")
reunion_music = pygame.mixer.Sound("05 - Reunion.ogg")
rebels_be_music = pygame.mixer.Sound("06 - Rebels Be.ogg")
'''

### create music list
music_lst = ['opening_music', 'prelude_music', 'nations_rage_music', 
             'sanctuary_music', 'reunion_music', 'rebels_be_music']

### window configuration:
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Alarm Clock")
window.configure(background='gray')

### clock function:
def ticktock():
    clock_time_string = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    clock.config(text = clock_time_string)
    clock.after(200,ticktock)

### alarm set label:
tk.Label(window, text = "Alarm Set", fg = "black", bg = 'grey', font = "none 12 bold").grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = 'W')

### alarm string entry box:
alarm_string = tk.Entry(window, width = 20, bg = 'white')
alarm_string.grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = 'W')

### pick alarm sound menu
def change(*args):
    var.get()

tk.Label(text = "Alarm Sounds", fg = 'black', bg = 'gray', font = 'none 12 bold').grid(row = 4, column = 0, sticky = 'W')
music_var = tk.StringVar(window)
music_var.set(music_lst[0])
music_var.trace('w', change)

options1 = tk.OptionMenu(window, music_var, music_lst[0], music_lst[1], music_lst[2], music_lst[3], music_lst[4], music_lst[5])
options1.configure(window, font = "none 12 bold").grid(row = 5, column = 0, sticky = 'W')
options1.pack()


### alarm function
def alarm(alarm_string_hour):
    while alarm_string:
        if alarm_string == clock_time_string('%H:%M:%S'):
            pass
            ## play sound
            ## try / except
            ## clear alarm

clock = tk.Label(window, font = ('times', 100, 'bold'), bg = 'grey')
clock.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = 'W')
ticktock()
clock.mainloop()
```

Comment: The error message should always tell you what line caused the error, so you should know for certain

Comment: @Reedinationer well, it doesn't, hence why I'm asking

Comment: The error on my machine is `NameError: name 'Label' is not defined` perhaps you meant `from tkinter import *`?

Comment: @Reedinationer I was wondering that too but I had that before and it was throwing the same error, most of the examples of drop down menus showed 'import tkinter as tk' and had 'tk.Tk()', or similar, throughout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of your problem is this line, which has two fundamental bugs:

```
options1.configure(window, font = "none 12 bold").grid(row = 5, column = 0, sticky = 'W')
```

The first bug is that the `configure` method doesn't accept the argument `window`. That is what is actually causing the error. If you remove it, that error goes away.

The second problem is that `options1.configure(...)` returns `None`, so you're effectively doing `None.grid(row = 5, column = 0)`, which will throw an error. You need to move the call to `grid` to a separate line. Also, the line after that calls `pack`, which you need to remove altogether.

The fixed code looks like this:

```
options1.configure(font = "none 12 bold")
options1.grid(row = 5, column = 0, sticky = 'W')
```

Comment: why don't I have to tie the drop down list to the window like with the other labels and text boxes?

Comment: @cwr1: you do, and you did when you created it. You can’t do it when you call `configure`

Answer (score 0):

I edited your post to eliminate most the errors. Namely

- `.grid(sticky=W)` should be -> `.grid(sticky='W')`
- I used consistent formatting for `import tkinter as tk`

  - i.e. `Label()` -> `tk.Label()`
  - `Entry()` -> `tk.Entry()`
    Still though I get an error different from your post:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/rparkhurst/PycharmProjects/Workspace/workspace.py", line 66, in <module>
    options1.configure(window, font = "none 12 bold").grid(row = 5, column = 0, sticky = 'W')
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1330, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1321, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-use"
```

So let's go over how to read this cause it seems you don't understand. You can see at the top `line 66` (every error will look like this and **will undoubtedly tell you what line it was on**) So how do we fix the error? Well let's look at the line (also part of the error traceback):

```
options1.configure(window, font = "none 12 bold").grid(row = 5, column = 0, sticky = 'W')
```

Hmmm well it looks like it is mad at us for something to do with `self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)`. How about we just comment out that line and see what happens?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/rparkhurst/PycharmProjects/Workspace/workspace.py", line 68, in <module>
    options1.pack()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1990, in pack_configure
    + self._options(cnf, kw))
_tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager pack inside . which already has slaves managed by grid
```

Hmm still not the error you posted, but we're getting somewhere! Seems you are also mixing `.grid()` and `.pack()` (not supposed to do that) We'll just switch it to `.grid()` and use the default settings (you can change that on your own). Bam it works!

Final result:

```
import sys
import tkinter as tk
import time
#import pygame

#pygame.init()

### load sounds
'''
opening_music = pygame.mixer.Sound("01 - Opening.ogg")
prelude_music = pygame.mixer.Sound("02 - Prelude.ogg")
nations_rage_music = pygame.mixer.Sound("03 - Nations Rage.ogg")
sanctuary_music = pygame.mixer.Sound("04 - Sanctuary.ogg")
reunion_music = pygame.mixer.Sound("05 - Reunion.ogg")
rebels_be_music = pygame.mixer.Sound("06 - Rebels Be.ogg")
'''

### create music list
music_lst = ['opening_music', 'prelude_music', 'nations_rage_music',
             'sanctuary_music', 'reunion_music', 'rebels_be_music']

### window configuration:
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Alarm Clock")
window.configure(background='gray')

### clock function:
def ticktock():
    clock_time_string = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    clock.config(text = clock_time_string)
    clock.after(200,ticktock)

### alarm set label:
tk.Label(window, text = "Alarm Set", fg = "black", bg = 'grey', font = "none 12 bold").grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = 'W')

### alarm string entry box:
alarm_string = tk.Entry(window, width = 20, bg = 'white')
alarm_string.grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = 'W')

### pick alarm sound menu
def change(*args):
    var.get()

tk.Label(text = "Alarm Sounds", fg = 'black', bg = 'gray', font = 'none 12 bold').grid(row = 4, column = 0, sticky = 'W')
music_var = tk.StringVar(window)
music_var.set(music_lst[0])
music_var.trace('w', change)

options1 = tk.OptionMenu(window, music_var, music_lst[0], music_lst[1], music_lst[2], music_lst[3], music_lst[4], music_lst[5])
#options1.configure(window, font = "none 12 bold").grid(row = 5, column = 0, sticky = 'W')
options1.grid()


### alarm function
def alarm(alarm_string_hour):
    while alarm_string:
        if alarm_string == clock_time_string('%H:%M:%S'):
            pass
            ## play sound
            ## try / except
            ## clear alarm

clock = tk.Label(window, font = ('times', 100, 'bold'), bg = 'grey')
clock.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = 'W')
ticktock()
clock.mainloop()
```

Seems you were trying to do something illegal with `options1`. A good idea when you're not sure what you **can** do is try `print(dir(some_variable))`. This will list all methods and attributes of the variable you can access. You can also read some documentation. For `tkinter` I prefer to use [this documentation source](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/)

Comment: Okay, yeah it worked. Not sure why but the only line # it gave me was from the 'init__.py' It didn't give me anything from my code and google was no help.Why would there be something ilegal there if the other ones were almost exactly the same?

Comment: @cwr1 Each widget type has different configuration options that are allowed. So while you may be able to specify a font on a `Label()` maybe you can't on a `OptionMenu`. If you are looking for more customization you should look into `ttk` (themed tkinter) as there is more options available, but the trade-off is that `ttk` programs are more involved and difficult.

Comment: I'll work my way up to that. Right now I'm just trying to build a portfolio to advent a career change. Much appreciated. Too many obfuscate their answers and make it seem like they're gatekeeping by trying to frustrate

Comment: @cwr1 I don't understand what you mean by "gatekeeping by trying to frustrate". I taught myself programming from books where it's the opposite and they give you more code than you can handle/understand. I learned `tkinter` from [this python GUI cookbook](https://www.amazon.com/Python-Programming-Cookbook-Burkhard-Meier/dp/1785283758/ref=sr_1_12_sspa?keywords=python+GUI&qid=1554409222&s=gateway&sr=8-12-spons&psc=1) which you might be able to find a PDF of online for free.

Comment: @cwr1 If this answered your question though it's common practice on SO to click the check mark by the post so future users know this answer was relevant without having to read it :D

Comment: I get a lot of overly complicated answers that just look like babble and do a poor job of explaining things because they feel like I should understand what they're talking about. Yours wasn't so I'm thanking you for that

Comment: You didn't actually address the problem of the original code. You simply removed the line of code causing the error rather than fixing it. While you provided some useful information, you completely skipped over the root cause of the error.